# Searching for C++ function declarations and implementations in multiple files using Bash

Tags: c++, regex, linux, bash, grep

I want to write a script that receives a project folder and a function name as parameters and returns all declarations and implementations found in all the files in all subfolders. Code in the project is C++. I can use tools like grep and bash scripting.

So for example:

```
./search.sh Project1 multiply
```

Would return:

```
Definition:

int Multiply(bool b, string s); found in file /include/file1.h on line 53

Implementation: 

int Multiply(bool b, string s) {
  int xx = 10;
  functionCall(xx);
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    somethingElse();
    blabla = blabla;
  }
}
```

This would work for multiple implementations/definitions as well, not just the first one found.

**What I've tried so far:**

I tried using grep to search all files and look for different patterns. I've managed to extract the definitions of the function, but I have no clue how to find the implementation (which is in a file with the same name as the file in which the definition was found, except it's a `.cpp` file not a `.h`).

Also how do I know up to which line I want to search in the implementation code block? I can't just search till the first `}`, because there could be other code blocks inside the implementation.

Comment: One does not simply parse C++ with a regex.  C++ is not regular, and you need something a lot more complex then a regular expression to parse it successfully.

Comment: You cannot parse C++ reliably with a bash script. You need a compiler. Look into clang tooling.

Comment: Something like Clang-AST can be used to get all functions.

Comment: @Jesper    I know using Bash and RegEx is stupid for this. If I could choose something else I would. But this is for an assigment (not regular homework, not just looking for people to do my homework for me). I don't have any good ideas on how to do this cleanly, so I'm asking for suggestions here.

Comment: It is quite impossible to parse C or C++ using regex, because the syntax and line splits are many and various. What I often do is capture the output of `nm` on the compiled object file then grep for those symbol names, but even that is quite difficult - even more so in c++

Comment: The compiler pre-processor may also be able to help you by emitting info for each symbol it finds.